# Tabbing have issue if next field is readonly

Tags: odoo, readonly, togglebutton, odoo-14, tabindex

I want to fill the fields using tab key and it is working fine in all cases but if next field is read-only then it doesn't work and even for the toggle buttons it doesn't make focus on toggle fields.
I tried using tabindex on these fields but it doesn't works and grouping structure changes doesn't fit in my case.

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share your attempt code?

Comment: hello bhavesh, I have tried implementing tabindex=0 to all the readonly fields. After that i have also tried to change tabindex in web module.